# toLocaleDateString() not working for Kazakhstan language

Tags: javascript

I tried to turn my date format to Kazakh but it is not working as expected. It still shows English month

```js
window.settings = {
  lang: 'kk'
}
const dateOptions = { month: 'long', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric' };
const time24HourFormatOptions = { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', hour12: false };
const time12HourFormatOptions = { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' };
debugger;
const langToLocale = { en: 'en-GB', sv: 'sv-SE', ar: 'ar', zh: 'zh-CN', kk: 'kk', ru: 'ru-RU', de: 'de', pt: 'pt', 'pt-BR':'pt-BR'};
function toLocaleBasedDate(date) {
  var date = new Date(date);
  debugger;
  return date.toLocaleDateString(langToLocale[settings.lang], dateOptions);
}

console.log(toLocaleBasedDate("04/26/2021"))
```

**Output**

[image: this is how it looks like]

[image: inspect view]

Comment: try to write it like: `kk: 'kk-KZ'`

Comment: Can you show a more minimal example that doesn't depend on some interpolated values we can't see…?

Comment: @poPaTheGuru it did not work.

Comment: @deceze I added some images. Hope it will make you more clear.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please remove all server code and replace settings.lang with actual content of `@(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewBag.CurrentCulture)? Model.Layout.CurrentCultureCode.Trim() : ViewBag.CurrentCulture.Trim()`

Comment: @YashmikaKuruppu: you should be able to reduce this to a 1- or 2-line example that demonstrates the problem. Strip out everything that's not relevant to the specific question.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Can you see now?

Comment: I fixed the  snippet.

Comment: Snippet gives me `2021 ж. 26 сәуір` in Firefox. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @connexo I get "26 April 2021" in Chrome

Comment: I get `26. April 2021` in Brave.

Comment: @connexo I get that for lang:de

Comment: Seems to use the browser locale then.

Comment: @connexo It probably rather means that some browsers/systems support the "kk" locale and others don't.

Comment: @connexo How can I use this?